# jquery tabs not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add jQuery tabs into a page. I'm unclear where my code breaks.
This website uses other jQuery APIs, but jQuery.noConflict(); didn't help.

What am I missing here?

```js
< link rel = "stylesheet"
href = "//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" >
  < script src = "//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" > < /script>
<script src="/ / code.jquery.com / ui / 1.11.4 / jquery - ui.js "></script>

<script>
$(function() {
$( "#
tabs " ).tabs();
});
</script>
```

```html
<p>Testing tab jQuery</p>
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">TAB ONE</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">TAB TWO</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">TAB THREE</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your script/link tags are not proper

Comment: <a href='somefile'> </a>  ...   also get rid of those extra spaces

Answer (score 0):

Just copied your code into [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/2uquyu7n/), and improved your code 
1. removed some space and add `http:` in including jquery and jquery-ui script src attributes.
2. `$( "#tabs " ).tabs();`  will be one line.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo by User86745458</title>      
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$( "#tabs " ).tabs();
});
//]]> 
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Testing tab jQuery</p>
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">TAB ONE</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">TAB TWO</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">TAB THREE</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. But still not working. Chrome javascript console audit shows 17 external javascript resources. Seems like I'm up against script conflicts.

Comment: Well, it ended with the support for the CMS saying they don't support additional jQuery or javascript third party code. If you ever have the potential to work with YourMembership CMS just turn away and don't look back.